# How to access react state from Google Chart event callbacks

Tags: reactjs, callback, google-visualization

```
{
            eventName: "select",
            callback(chartWrapper) {
                // how to get this.state 
                // this return undefined because of instance is different
                console.clear();
                console.log(chartWrapper)
            }
        },
```

How to get React, this.state inside in callback of react-google-chart

I am happy to use a hackish way.

Comment: will you please share the rest of the code?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I believe my question here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70942575/how-to-access-angular-component-property-from-a-google-charts-callback) is related (Angular instead of React). My example has a bit more detail and hopefully will get a reply.